# How do I change the method modifiers that Intellij auto creates from unknown usage?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-generation

In Intellij, if I use a method without its definition, IntelliJ suggests to create the method. When created, the method always has *public* as its access modifier. How can I change this default setting to package-local?

Answer (score 1):

Intellij provides a setting for that:

File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> Code Generation -> Default Visibility

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: 

You currently can't change the default value.

**Longer answer**:

After you generate the method (using either <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) the return-type will be highlighted with the mouse-cursor. At that point you should hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> again and you'll get to choose the modifier, like in the following example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, alfasin. Unfortunately, the return-type is not highlighted in the way you described in my Intellij 13 Community Edition. Highlighted 'with' a red rectangle around it, the auto-suggested return type is waiting for my confirming the type with the cursor blinking at the end of the return-type. In such a situation, nothing happens when I hit Alt+Enter. The only thing I can do is to change or confirm the return-type, and then the cursor moves away to another position such as to the first line of the created method body. Any more help will be appreciated.

Comment: @BillyKi try the following: after the method is created (and you have the red rectangle) press `Esc` then make sure the cursor is on the return type and press `Alt+Enter`

Comment: Thanks again. I tried but it doesn't work. With first pressing Esc, the blue highlight wrapping the text disappears while the read rectangle still exists, which means you can now append texts at the end of the return type literals ('void' in your example above). With second pressing Esc key, the red rectangle disappears and the cursor move away to the first line of the created method body. To be able to press Alt+Enter, the cursor I think should stay at the return type.

Comment: Do I have to change the end position of this auto-creation at the IntelliJ settings, which may be like a predefined live template variable $END$ indicates the position of the cursor after the template is expanded.